# How can i add a legend to a Here map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, here-api

i am working with a here map and i need to add a legend. I am currently trying to create a new component called legend using react-leaflet. My question is if there is another way in creating a legend?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to add a marker like this ? :

```
var berlinMarker = new H.map.Marker({
  lat:52.5192,
  lng:13.4061
});
map.addObject(berlinMarker);
```

[image]

Source: [Here API](https://developer.here.com/develop/javascript-api)

Comment: I added a photo to my post. I tried using react-leaflet but with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I could only find about [marker objects](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.15.1/dev_guide/topics/marker-objects.html) and the [overlays](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.15.1/dev_guide/topics/overlays.html), but the main issue with them is that they are positioned on the map, not over a legend should.

So i suggest you use a `<View></View>` and put your legend in it and with a few css tricks make it overlay the map.

ex :  `style={{position: 'absolute', right: 0, top: -YOUR_LEGEND_HEIGHT}}`